# Cursor in middle of text in batch

Tags: batch-file

I am looking for a way to place the cursor between several lines of echo commands so it appears that the pause is in the center of the code, rather than at the end, while still displaying the last line of text and not continuing to the next label until hitting anykey. is this possible?
I want to have the appearance that the last line of actual text is a footer, seperat from the above text.

At the moment, my sequencing looks similar to this:

```
:LABEL
CLS
ECHO text1
ECHO.
ECHO.
(want the PAUSE to appear here)
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO text2
PAUSE (while the PAUSE is really here to prevent text2 from being lost)
GOTO OTHERLABEL
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Clear as mud - I can't figure out what you are asking. Try to clarify, and perhaps show what the results should look like (formatted as code).

Comment: I need some text at the foot of the label to display a password, while having the blinking cursor above it. when the file is running, it should look as though the pause is just after the first block of text. it is for a word game, giving the ability to resume where you left it, if you had to leave.

Comment: You need to be a bit clearer in your question. Are you wanting to loop back to the top again? Or jump to a separate part of the code? Or do you want to repeat sections of you code many times with different values?

Comment: Neither, just asking for a way to make it appear that the PAUSE in the running batch is before the second block of text, while still displaying both blocks of text. It was a silly question. I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you are asking, correct me if I am wrong. You want this functionality:

```
echo hello
pause
echo bye
```

But you want to switch the location on the screen of the pause and echo bye. If so, that is not easy. I suppose you could use a vbscript that once the first pause runs in the above code, would send a key to the batch file, which would echo. a ton of times and then pause again, and then the vbscript could scroll up in the batch file. It's not worth it.

Comment: Thank you. That does sound not worth it. Instead, is there a way to hide the blinking cursor? I have it so the PAUSE message is not there, but the blinking cursor still appears.

Comment: There is none that I know of.

Comment: Please disregard that comment, I am on mobile and it won't let me save edits :/  What you could do is first echo "Press space to continue..." and then use a choice command to proceed.